# how to access dgraph ratel

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability, dgraph

I've installed a highly available dgraph cluster using kubernetes. Now I want to know how to access the dgraph ratel UI. I cannot access it by using master's-ip:8000. In simple words, I need the dgraph-ratel's URL.

Comment: Did you install it in minikube or in a real cluster?

Comment: in a real cluster, used these instruction https://docs.dgraph.io/deploy/#ha-cluster-setup-using-kubernetes  -shudipta-sharma

Answer (score 2):

You can also access `dgraph-ratel` from outside the cluster in case you use cloud environment.

Obtain External IP for `dgraph-ratel-public` service:

`kubectl get svc dgraph-ratel-public -o wide`

And you can reach `dgraph-ratel` on the address: `http://<External IP>:8000`

Comment: external ip is in pending state. what shoul i do now?

Comment: Usually it takes some time once Cloud provider propagates External IP for `LoadBalancer` service

Comment: its 5days since ive installed dgraph, but the ratle public is still in a pending state.
@mk_sta

Comment: Check `dgraph-ratel-public` service to catch any event there: `kubectl describe svc dgraph-ratel-public`.

Answer (score 1):

The doc you mentioned in the comment says the `dgraph-ratel` is using port `8000`. So after port-forwarding use http://localhost:8000.

Comment: im using it in cloud environment. kubectl get svc dgraph-ratel-public -o wide this cmd will show me the ip address to access, but the external ip is in pending state

Comment: If you are using a real cluster, then you should get an array of external ips in your `LoadBalancer` type service yaml. But if you are using minikube then you will never get external ips. It will always remain in pending state.